# Is there only one possible solution to homogenous DE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

When solving a homogenous DE, I am suppose to find a variable to substitute into the DE such as

$$ let  ,  u=\frac{y}{x}$$

Im wondering  if can have multiple answers to one DE depending on what I choose as the substitute?

For example:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{y-x}{y+x} $$
 $$ let  ,  u=y+x$$
 $$ then   ,  du=\frac{dy}{dx} +1$$

I ended up getting  $$ -y-x= x+C$$, however the solution in the back of the book has ln's. Which is why Im wondering if there are more than one solution to a problem like this.

Comment: According to you, $y = -2x$ should be a solution, however $dy/dx = -2 \neq 3 = (y-x)/(y+x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Case**

$$u = \dfrac{y}{x}  \implies y = u x \implies y' = u + u' x = \dfrac{\dfrac{y}{x} - 1}{\dfrac{y}{x}+1} = \dfrac{u-1}{u+1}$$

Solving the Separable Equation, we get

$$\dfrac{1}{2} \ln(u^2 + 1) + \arctan(u) = -\ln x + c$$

Substitute $u(x) = \dfrac{y}{x}$.

**Second Case**

$$u = y + x \implies y = u - x \implies y' = u' - 1 = \dfrac{y-x}{y+x} = \dfrac{u - 2 x}{u}$$

To solve this, we use the substitution, $u = x y$ and get the same result after.

Do you see how the first method was much better as it reduced the DEQ to a separable one without having to make a second substitution, which takes you back to the first case anyway?

Regardless, you get the same result.

Comment: Ahh yes , thank you!